# Javascript superclass run constructor every time

Tags: javascript

I have a super, and a subclass in javascript. Every time I create a new subclass instance, the superclass constructor works strange.

```
function sup() {
  var elem = document.createElement('div');

  this.add = function(str) {
    elem.innerHTML = str;
    document.body.appendChild(elem);
  }

  this.remove = function() {
    document.body.removeChild(elem);
  };

  //...
}

function sub(str) {
  this.add(str);

  //...
}

sub.prototype = new sup();
```

Only one div (`elem`) is created, and renamed again, and again. How should I rewrite my class system, to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Its good to create the member methods in the prototype. So, `add` should be in `sup`'s prototype.
2. You are creating only one `div` element and adding the same `div` element to the body again and again.
3. `sub`'s prototype should be created from `sup`'s prototype.

The fixed code would look like this

```
function sup() {}

sup.prototype.add = function(str) {
    var elem = document.createElement('div');
    elem.innerHTML = str;
    document.body.appendChild(elem);
}

function sub(str) {
    this.add(str);
}

sub.prototype = Object.create(sup.prototype);
```

Comment: but if more function wants to use the `elem`? Then I can't put the `var elem = document.createElement('div')` into the add function

Comment: for example if I would like to write a sup.remove function

Comment: @IterAtor Please edit your question and include the actual problem in detail, probably with an example.

Comment: @IterAtor Which `elem` has to be removed?

Comment: Every time I create a new instance of the subclass, a new div should be created, which I can add, or delete. But this is just an example.

Comment: @IterAtor Add/delete to the document?